# What's the best way to read texture info from an image file and get to the pixels using SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl

You can create a texture in SDL2 using CreateTexture() and then get access to the pixels in that texture using LockTexture().  But in order to do so you need to have passed the SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING flag to the CreateTexture call.

There's a fairly standard helper library for loading images called SDL_image.  I use it to read image files into textures (textures are graphics card resident images for the casual observer).  I'm currently loading my textures using IMG_LoadTexture().  My problem is I can't see how to set the SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING flag in this case.  So I can't get pixel data for textures loaded with SDL_image?

The reason I want to get to the pixels is to extract nine-patch data from them.  (I may well end up having 9 textures).  So I only need this info once at the start and I only need to read the texture data, not write it.  I'd also like to use preexisting image file reading libraries if at all possible.

So the question is:  What's the best way to read texture info from an image file and get to the pixels using SDL2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided it was better to do it with surfaces and then convert to textures.  This code works.  It only does the top left corner of the nine-patch to keep it simple. (This also ignores the complication of the nine patch sizing info in the first row and column of the nine patch image).

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

NinePatch::NinePatch(const string fname, SDL_Renderer * renderer) {

    // get the surface and the bits per pixel
    SDL_Surface * surface = IMG_Load(fname.c_str());
    int bytes_per_pixel = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;

    // keep things simple by only looking at 4 byte/pixel nine-patches
    if (bytes_per_pixel != 4) {
        log_msg("Loading " + fname + 
                " expecting pixel data to be 4 but it has: " + 
                to_string(bytes_per_pixel));
        exit(1);
    }

    // offsets into the surface that divide the surface into a nine-patch
    unsigned int left, right, top, bottom;

    // find the widths we need by looking at the top row of pixels
    byte_t * ptr = (byte_t*)surface->pixels;
    uint32_t pixel, last_pixel = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < surface->w; i++) {

        // we know they're 4 byte pixels cause otherwise we don't get here.
        pixel = *(uint32_t*)ptr;

        // look for "edges" in the top row of pixel data
        if (pixel > last_pixel) {
            left = i;
        }
        else if (pixel < last_pixel) {
            right = i;            
        }
        last_pixel = pixel;

        // get the next pixel across
        ptr += bytes_per_pixel;
    }


    // find the heights we need by looking at the left column of pixels
    ptr = (byte_t*)surface->pixels;
    last_pixel = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < surface->h; i++) {

        // we know they're 4 byte pixels cause otherwise we don't get here.
        pixel = *(uint32_t*)ptr;

        // look for "edges" in the left column of pixel data
        if (pixel > last_pixel) {
            top = i;
        }
        else if (pixel < last_pixel) {
            bottom = i;
        }
        last_pixel = pixel;

        // get the next pixel down
        ptr += bytes_per_pixel * surface->w;
    }

    // SDL interprets each pixel as a 32-bit number, so our masks 
    // must depend on the endianness (byte order) of the machine 
    Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
    rmask = 0xff000000;
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;
    amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
    rmask = 0x000000ff;
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;
    amask = 0xff000000;
#endif

    const uint32_t unused_flags = 0;
    const int pixel_size = 32; // in bits

    // scratch surface we use for breaking the nine-patch 
    // surface into little textures.
    SDL_Surface * s;
    SDL_Rect src_rect;

    // create a surface to hold the top left corner
    s = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(unused_flags, left, top, 
                             pixel_size, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

    // copy part of the nine-patch image surface into the new surface
    src_rect.x = 0;
    src_rect.y = 0;
    src_rect.w = left;
    src_rect.h = top;
    SDL_BlitSurface(surface, &src_rect, s, NULL);

    // convert the new corner surface into a texture
    top_left_texture =  SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, s);

    // free the scratch surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(s);
}
```